# Как получить последнее значение по идентификатору в зависимости от времени

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, анализ-данных

Допустим у нас есть DataFrame, где у нас есть `id`, время условно получения значения, и само значение.

Пример:

[image: Пример датафрейма]

Варианты разброса значения по времени могут быть разные.

Вот еще пример без NaN:

[image: Пример датафрейма без NaN]

Как получить последнее значение по времени для каждого `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
df.sort_values("Время").groupby("id")["Значение"].last()
```